# Is it possible to set a Selenium::Driver::Proxy after initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently using Capybara and Chromedriver to run feature tests in our Rails application. At the moment I can see that it is possible to set the proxy via args when you initialize the driver.

```
    Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
        app,
        browser: :chrome,
        args: [
          '--window-size=1240,1400',
          "--proxy-server=#{s.url}",
          '--proxy-bypass-list=127.0.0.1'
        ]
      )
    end
```

However, I only want specific tests to proxy a particular port, because I am also using Capybara::Discoball to boot up a Sinatra app as the application I am proxying external requests to. So I need to be able to change the proxy after it has initialized to the port of the currently booted Sinatra app. Is this possible after initialization?

Answer (score 0):

No but you can register another driver with another name and then specify to use that for the tests that require it. Assuming you're using the default capybara rspec configuration that would be something like

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  # register the driver without proxy here
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome_proxy do |app|
  # register the driver with proxy config here
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome # register default JS driver

it "does something that doesn't need proxy", js: true do
   # test that doesn't use the proxy config
end

it "does something that needs proxy", driver: :selenium_chrome_proxy do
  # test that uses proxy
end
```